# DataGridView row added event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView and I bind a List to the DataSource.

I already have the right columns and I map exactly the fields. What I'm trying to do is handling a sort of `RowAdded` or `RowDataBound` (like in aspx GridView) event.

The only event that I found is `RowsAdded` but no matter how many items I have, it is fired only 4 times the first time i bound, and twice the other times, with values

e.RowCount:1 e.RowIndex:0
e.RowCount:[n-1] e.RowIndex:1 *where n is the number of my items

is there a way I can get to a handle for each item?

EDIT: without changing the `DataSource =` binding method

Comment: Do you need a callback each time a row is added, or is it sufficient to have a collection of all the rows? If the latter, does the `Rows` property have a valid set of all rows at the time `RowsAdded` is invoked?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain very well.
I need a callback each time a row is added.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: did you find a method to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I honestly don't remember. I probably changed approach or abandoned the idea of the progress bar.

Answer (score 23):

I just ran into this same issue. You can get the index and range of the rows that were added from the event args passed to the RowsAdded event handler. Use this information to loop through each of the added rows. `e.RowIndex` and `e.RowCount` will let you determine the added rows.

```
private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = e.RowIndex; index <= e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1; index++) {
        DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[index];

        // Do something with the added row here
        // Raise a custom RowAdded event if you want that passes individual rows.
    }
}
```

If you wanted you could inherit datagridview and make your own grid that throws a "RowAdded" event inside the loop above.

Comment: Code Correction: DataGridView1.Rows[index];

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me is using a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource. Add the list to that and then use the BindingSource as the grid DataSource. This then acts as a go-between for the grid and data.

There are then several events that can then be used from the bindingsouce. One of those is AddingNew. You can also use it to capture rows being add or removed, as well as several other things.