# Datagrid displays differently the first time my form is loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, repository-pattern

I have a datagridview that displays information on books in a "library". However for some reason the first time the form is loaded it displays the button column I have in the first column instead of the last column as well all of the buttons in the buttons column are active.  When I call the same method after the form is loaded by clicking on another button it shows the datagridview as intended where the button column is the right most column and where book copies are 0, the button in the button column is disabled.  It continues to work perfectly thereafter, just never on the first load.

Heres the code for the method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets datagrid to show all books that have available copies.  Adds buttons to the last columns.  Resizes datagrid. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void showAvailCopies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        this.dt.set_availableBookView();   // dt is a datable and set_availBookView is an extension method I wrote to set up the columns of the table. 
        foreach (Book book in this.bookService.getAll())
        {
            this.dt.Rows.Add(
                book.Title,
                book.Author.Name.ToString(),
                book.ISBN,
                this.copyService.getAvailableCopies(book.Title).Count(),
                loanService.numOfLoansByBook(book.Title)
                );

        }
        this.addButtonColumn("Loan", "Loan Book"); // Goes through the usual add button column code with parameters to set the button text and button column header.  
        this.dataGrid.DataSource = dt;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["Copies Available"].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                DataGridViewDisableButtonCell buttonCell =
                    (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["Loan Book"];
                buttonCell.Enabled = false;
                buttonCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        } 

        this.autoSizeGrid();
    }
```

Could it be that when loading data from my database ( done through `bookService.getAll()` ) that the data is loaded slower than the button column is loaded?  And hence when I check for 0's in the available copies column it never returns true?

I realize there's a fair amount of code I'm not showing.  I was hoping maybe it would be something simple I'm missing rather then dump a huge amount of code here.  If you need to see any of the code from any other of my methods please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you are trying to update the grid before it has been rendered (first time).  On subsequent posts it works because the grid has already been rendered, albeit on the *previous* post back. My guess would be that first time around, your foreach loop doesn't actually loop through anything?

This answer describes how to wire up the RowAdded event, you could use that to perform your button logic (this is worth looking at even if my diagnosis is wrong!)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3846937/1514883

Comment: Ah yes!  This is totally the clue I was missing.  I did some more research and found that if I added the method to the load event-handler it rendered out my datagridview first before trying to add information to it.  After learning this it seems that its probably a good idea to always use the load delegate for forms.  The link was also quite enlightening thank you!