# how to recognize newly added rows directly to datagridview - c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have bound a `datatable` to a `datagridview`  and allowed the user to `delete` `update`, and `insert` new records directly to this `datagridview`

Now I want to know how do I recognize newly inserted row/rows ?

I want to get new **row/rows** and `delete` `update`, or `insert` them 
into SQL server database.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView row added event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653137/datagridview-row-added-event)

Comment: @DanWilson this for added rows how about updated and deleted rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 different ways - depend on your use case:

#### 1st: Server side

Use this concept if you want to track the changes with multiple session per user, submit all changes to server side and track the changes datetime and save status.

#### 2nd: Client side

Use this concept if you want to track the changes on client side regardless of the multi-session per user, basically, add 1 extra column to track the changes history -better to keep it hidden-

Comment: Pleae would mind to give example or links for each case?

Comment: Windows forms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the `DataTable.GetChanges` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk

or better look into the `DataAdapter.Update` method [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update)